How to integrate Orb with a React application?
I am trying to integrate Orb into my React application. To me it looks like Orb seems to write directly to its own canvas element. Is there a hook that I could use?

You own the container element where you want Orb to create a canvas in. E.g. You can have <div ref={container} ... , hook with const container = useRef(null); and then in the effect give Orb initialization with container.current where Orb will create canvas in.
